# Proving if a function is continuous or not

Tags: continuity

Can somebody explain how to solve this problem:

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

The first question is asking you to show that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \frac{1}{x} = 0.$$

Hint:

> Use the fact that $-1 \le \sin \frac{1}{x} \le 1$ for all $x \ne 0$.

---

For the second question, you just need to determine whether
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sin \frac{1}{x}$$
is equal to $0$ or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|f(x)-f(0)|=\left|x\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|\leq |x|=|x-0|.$

While as $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ oscillates as $x\rightarrow 0.$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\epsilon >0$
Clearly $|f(x)-f(0)|<x$ for all $x$
if we set $\delta=\epsilon$ we obtain 
$|x-0|=|x|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(0)|<x$